# Python3 print raw byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I want a simple, one-liner solution that will print a byte.

```
python3 -c 'print("A", end="")' | xxd -p
python3 -c 'print("\x41", end="")' | xxd -p
```

The output from both lines is 41, as expected

```
python3 -c 'print("\xec", end="")' | xxd -p
```

This outputs: `c3ac`

I think this has something to do with the fact that python3 uses utf-8 as default encoding, however I couldn't find a simple solution for this.

Basically, I want the python3 equivalent of:

```
perl -e 'print "\xec"'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strings printed are written to the `sys.stdout` object and *encoded to your system encoding*. What bytes are actually written depends on your system locale; your terminal is configured for UTF-8, so the U+00EC character is encoded to two bytes.

You need to write raw bytes to `sys.stdout.buffer` instead:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\xec")'
```

Note the `b` prefix.

Demo:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\xec")' | xxd -p
ec
```